# Newbie question about Jquery scope

Tags: jquery, scope

Quick question regarding a jquery scope in following example:

```
$(function(){
  var test;
  $.get('txtfile.txt', function(txtfile) {
      test = txtfile.split('\n');
  });
  console.log(test);
});
```

console returns 'test' is undefined. Could u please point me where im making a mistake.
Thanks.

Comment: jQuery has no concept of scope of its own - it's just a Javascript library.

Comment: :) well it wasnt directly scope in jquery, but rather the fact that im getting lost in jquery structure...

Answer (score 3):

`$.get` works asynchronously (The "A" in "Ajax" stands for "Asynchronous"). The success callback (which you are defining using the `function(){}` construct) is called only after the Ajax call has finished. When the code arrives at

```
console.log(test);
```

that has  not yet happened.

If you put the `console.log` call into the success callback, it will work as expected.

Comment: So everything that has to do with data accessed by $.get, has to be inside of success call back?

Comment: @uhandoh: Yes, the success callback has to do all the work. But the success callback is free to call whatever functions or methods it needs. The success callback also has access to things in the surround scope just like any other closure.